# Class is not added to the first div that is dynamically added

Tags: angular

In my angular app in onInit function i'm fetching some value and displaying it in this manner
user.component.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
  this.method={method:"fetchTickets",user:ntid,ticketId:"12332"}
  this.subscription1= this.userService.getTickets(this.method).subscribe(ticket =>{
  this.tickets=ticket.data;
})
```

user.component.html

```
  <div class="Users" id="foo">
  <div class="ruser mb-2" #tickets  *ngFor="let ticket of tickets" (click)="fetchMsg(ticket)">
    <div class="rname z-depth-2 hoverable {{ticket.id}}">
      <h5>{{ticket.id}}</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

So now on a button click i'm adding data to the start of tickets array which is being automatically displayed in the Users div but when i add a class to the first element i.e the one added after button click , that class is being applied to the second .rname div

```
fetcMsg(ticket)
{
  this.tickets.unshift({id:this.ticketRand,resolved:true,time:d});
  $('.rname:first').addClass('selected'); //this applies to the second rname 
  div
  $('.'+this.ticketRand).addClass('selected'); //this does not apply at all
 }
```

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try use the [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) directive.

```
<div class="Users" id="foo">
      <div class="ruser mb-2" #tickets  *ngFor="let ticket of tickets" (click)="fetchMsg(ticket)">
        <div [ngClass]="{'selected': ticket.id == ticketRand}" class="rname z-depth-2 hoverable {{ticket.id}}">
          <h5>{{ticket.id}}</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

The fetchMsg method would look something like the following:

```
fetchMsg(ticket){
  this.tickets.unshift({id:this.ticketRand,resolved:true,time:d});
 }
```

Comment: @aeshnaKashyap .. I've edited my answer to use the NgClass directive. Hopefully that works for you.